Assistance Needed on Invariant Curves in a $C^1$ Vector Field with Two Parameters
I've been exploring a problem for the past two months, and I would greatly appreciate your insights. I'm working with a $C^1$ vector field defined by the equation $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = f(\mathbf{x}; \alpha, \beta )$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parameters.
My goal is to find conditions under which exists curves in the $(\alpha, \beta)$ parameter plane that leave the vector field unchanged. To approach this, I've been trying to solve the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{J_{\alpha \text{,} \beta }} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial \alpha} & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial \beta} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \alpha} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \beta}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{J_{\alpha \text{,} \beta }}
 \begin{bmatrix}
\Delta \alpha \\
\Delta \beta
\end{bmatrix}
= \mathbf{0} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
However, I haven't been able to identify nonlinear curves that satisfy this condition. If anyone has tackled a similar problem or could offer any guidance on how to proceed with this problem, I would be incredibly grateful for your help.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions or ideas!
